# Having trouble compiling C code on ubuntu. (#include errors)

Tags: c, linux, ubuntu, header

I'm trying to compile a C program on the newest version of ubuntu, for the purpose of putting the compiled program on another machine later. However, when I compile with gcc prog.c -o prog, I get an error: "fatal error: asm/page.h: No such file or directory" Here are the headers:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <malloc.h>
#include <limits.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/uio.h>
#include <sys/mman.h>
#include <asm/page.h>
#include <asm/unistd.h>
```

I get an error at #include . It says fatal error: asm/page.h: No such file or directory. Like I said, I'm just looking to compile it. Is there a way for me to get the missing header or something? Thanks.

Comment: What is your program intended to do? Why does it include all the above mess? Show much more of your source code, not only the `#include` directives!

Answer (score 6):

These header files are not missing they have been moved. The ubuntu packagers moved things around and the location of the header files that used to be in '/usr/include/asm' are now in '/usr/include/asm-generic '

To fix, just add a link:

> sudo ln -s /usr/include/asm-generic /usr/include/asm

... or, maybe you are probably lacking build-essential. This is necessary to compile Code in linux .
 install build-essential

> sudo apt-get install build-essential

Now recreate the proper link:

> sudo ln -s /usr/include/asm-generic /usr/include/asm

Build-essential should install a /usr/include/asm-generic folder. If you lack such a folder reinstall build-essentials and verify the folder exists.

Does the /usr/include/asm-generic folder exist?

It is installed by build-essentials but examining it it is a dependency that installs it.

if /usr/include/asm-generic does not exist, try to install or reinstall linux-libc-dev.

That should create the asm-generic folder. If so delete that old link and relink asm to asm-generic.

Comment: Not only linking `asm` to `asm-generic` seems like really dirty hack, it is not likely to help anyway. On most recent Ubuntu 13.04, while directory `/usr/include/asm-generic` exists, `page.h` does not (and `build-essential` and `linux-libc-dev` are installed).

Comment: Okay, I installed build-essentials and created the link but I still receive the exact same error. /usr/include/asm-generic does exist, but it already existed before I installed build-essentials.

Answer (score 5):

Typically, `asm/page.h` only exists in Linux kernel tree, normally under `arch/<archname>/asm/page.h`, and should be used only be kernel code (or by kernel modules).

`stdio.h` and `stdlib.h`, on other hand, are not to be used in kernel code.
So, your original source code looks fishy at best. Most likely it never needed that `asm/page.h` in first place, and in reality it just needs something like `linux/types.h` (this is one of headers included by one of kernel's `asm/page.h`).

Comment: Actually the definitions which used to be in `asm/page.h` (like `PAGE_SIZE`) are in `sys/user.h`, not in `linux/types.h`.

Answer (score 0):

Additionally you can add this to your make file

`gcc -I /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu --your_other_arguments`

Comment: Here are some guidelines for [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).  This provided answer may be correct, but it could benefit from an explanation.