# Building Jonesforth - asm/unistd.h: No such file or directory

Tags: ubuntu, gcc, assembly, gnu-assembler, forth

When attempting to build [Jonesforth](https://github.com/nornagon/jonesforth/) (32-bit GNU Assembler program) on Ubuntu 16.04.4 64-bit  (Xenial Xerus), I'm seeing the following:

```
~/src/jonesforth $ make
gcc -m32 -nostdlib -static -o jonesforth jonesforth.S
jonesforth.S:1154:24: fatal error: asm/unistd.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
Makefile:11: recipe for target 'jonesforth' failed
```

Looking in the file `jonesforth.S`, I noticed the following lines:

```
//#include <asm-i386/unistd.h>  // You might need this instead
#include <asm/unistd.h>
```

I've tried using `asm-i386/unistd.h` instead, but that also didn't seem to help.

Is the best course of action to install more headers via `sudo apt install linux-headers...`? If so, which should I go with? Should `linux-headers-generic` be sufficient?

Or, should I change the header that `jonesforth.S` is referring to?

Comment: Do you have `build-essential` installed?  It should depend on `linux-libc-dev` which contains `/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/include/asm/unistd.h` (which includes `unistd_64.h` or `unistd_32.h`, or x32, depending on -m32 or not.  Possibly a dup of [Having trouble compiling C code on ubuntu. (#include errors)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19310541)

Comment: @PeterCordes Hi Peter! Yup, it looks like I have it installed. I see the following in the results of a `apt list --installed`: `build-essential/xenial,now 12.1ubuntu2 amd64 [installed]`.

Comment: @PeterCordes I added the following to the make recipe: `-I /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu`. And that seemed to do the trick! Thanks!

Comment: So I guess my next question is, is that the "idiomatic" way to get those headers in? I.e. to add that specific path to the GCC include path?

Comment: I think asm/unistd.h should be in the standard include path.  Something's misconfigured or buggy if `#include <asm/unistd.h>` doesn't work in a `.c` or `.S` file.  It works on my Arch Linux system, and on an old Ubuntu 15.10 system, using `gcc -c -m32 uni.S`.  I checked with `strace -f gcc ...` and it is using `/usr/include/i386-linux-gnu/` as part of the include path for `gcc -m32`.  Maybe later Ubuntu is configured differently, but my Arch system is up to date.

Answer (score 5):

Adding `-I /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu` to the make recipe seems to have solved the issue:

```
jonesforth: jonesforth.S
        gcc -I /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu -m32 -nostdlib -static $(BUILD_ID_NONE) -o $@ $<
```

Thanks to the suggestion from [Peter Cordes](https://stackoverflow.com/users/224132/peter-cordes) above!

Comment: This is incorrect! This file is for 64 bit assembly and leads to wrong code when used with 32 bit assembly. Let me look up the correct solution when I'm back home.

Comment: @fuz: That's a directory, and it contains `unistd_32.h`, `unistd_64.h`, and `unistd_x32.h`, with a `unistd.h` which conditionally includes the right one for the current mode.  (Each with the same contents as in `/usr/include/i386-linux-gnu`).  gcc on my system automatically sets the `-I` path to include `/usr/include/i386-linux-gnu` or `/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu` depending on -m32 or -m64.  So it could get the wrong headers for *other* files, but not `unistd.h`.  (`diff -ur` between the `asm` directories under those two paths finds no differences.)

Comment: @PeterCordes I'm pretty sure that OP just needs to install the appropriate 32 bit support files.  Let me check again.

Comment: What about OSX? (I can ask a separate question, but this is first search engine result)

Answer (score 4):

You need to install package `multilib`.