# How can I compile JonesForth on OS X v10.14 (Mojave)?

Tags: macos, gcc, macos-mojave, forth

Attempting to compile [JonesForth](http://git.annexia.org/?p=jonesforth.git;a=blob_plain;f=jonesforth.S;hb=HEAD) on OS X, it throws:

```
jonesforth.S:1154:10: fatal error: 'asm/unistd.h' file not found".
```

So I tried [this advice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53685776/building-jonesforth-asm-unistd-h-no-such-file-or-directory/53686051#53686051) for Linux, but it still complains.

This [PowerPC port](https://tech.labs.oliverwyman.com/blog/2007/10/04/jonesforth-ported-to-powerpc-and-mac-os-x/) throws other exceptions, like:

```
invalid instruction mnemonic 'bctr'
unexpected token in memory operand
```

Is there an OS X port around?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This [port of JonesForth](https://github.com/ruda/jonesforth-macintel) compiles on OS X.

Comment: The above link: [macintel port of Jonesforth](https://github.com/ruda/jonesforth-macintel) stopped working on MacOS Catalina onwards, in particular binaries are now required to be 64-bit.

For those interested to still run jonesforth on more recent Macs, I have [provided a 64bit port of jonesforth](https://github.com/klapauciusisgreat/jonesforth-MacOS-x64) does does work (at least passes all the tests).